# Fully react state management

Tags: reactjs

This is not an issue but rather a question.
I wanted to use React solely for my Global state management and pass the todos through useReducer and useContext and I wonder if this is by any means a right way to go. I was called out by a react coder that this way the components rerender when they aren't supposed to but my element inspection shows only the changed component rerenders. Would please guide me as whether or not I can continue developing this way or have to revert back to Mobx or redux or many other third party state manager libraries.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. If a combination of context and a global reducer works for you, then go for it.

Comment: Redux shares state of whole application stored in a single global "store". It could be a fully state management in react. According to [react state management libraries](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management), Redux is still the most popular libraries in 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and it's easier than ever thanks to the new hooks API! For very simple things like for instance, a global theme you can just create a context with [React.createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext), and [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

For a more robust solution, you can actually implement a Flux architecture with a combination of `useContext` and [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). Here's one I made earlier.

```
// AcmeContext.js

import React, { useReducer, createContext } from 'react'

const AcmeContext = createContext({})

const actions = {
  DO_SOMETHING: 'doSomething'
}

const actionCreators = dispatch => ({
  updateComment: comment => {
    dispatch({
      type: actions.DO_SOMETHING,
      payload: comment
    })
  }
})

// first paramter is your state, second is the action 
let reducer = (currentState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case actions.DO_SOMETHING:
      // important: return a NEW new object for this context, don't change the old currentState
      return { ...currentState, hello: payload }
    default:
      return
  }
}

// this component wraps any of the child components that you want to share state with
function AcmeProvider({ children, initialState }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const actions = actionCreators(dispatch)

  return (
    <AcmeContext.Provider value={{ state, actions }}>
      {children}
    </AcmeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { AcmeContext, AcmeProvider }
```

Then, you wrap the component you want to provide the context to with the exported provider.

```
// App.jsx

import { AcmeProvider } from './AcmeContext'
import TestComponent from './TestComponent'

render((
  <AcmeProvider initialState={{ hello: 'world' }}>
    <TestComponent />
  </AcmeProvider>
), document.querySelector('.app'))
```

Finally, you can call it from the child component.

```
// TestComponent.jsx

import { AcmeContext } from './AcmeContext'

export default () => {
  const { state, actions } = useContext(AcmeContext)

  return (
    <div>
      Hello {state.hello}!

      <button onClick={() => actions.updateComment('me')}>Set response on onClick to 'me'</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This does have a couple of downsides to a full Redux implementation. You don't get the Redux dev tools and you don't get things like `redux-thunk` which means you'll have to add that logic to the component and get the component to update the context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can totally use the default React APIs for full state management on a project. The introduction of hooks makes it easy to manage. `useContext` has slowly become my favourite hook because it removes the need for consumers and makes the JSX look a bit nicer.

If you are worried about things rerendering too many times, you can still use all of the tricks in the React Toolbox like `React.memo`.